# Cannot place a div correctly after vertical menu bar

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu bar on the left of my page, and when I try to put a simple 
DIV or a TABLE in the middle of the page it go on the bottom after my lateral menu.

Here is the CSS general code for the bar:

```
.generalMenuHome
{
  width:70px;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:#000;
  border-right:solid 2px #556CF0;
  min-height: 550px;
  position:relative;
}
```

I have more DIVs inside that bar here an example of one:

```
.logoInGenrealMenu
{
  position:absolute;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background-image:url(../insiteincludes/medias/logo.png);
  background-size:80%;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

I'm using ***position*** attributes well, right?

You can see my problem: https://postimg.org/image/qzju2dl8h/

[image: Capture]

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you also post the HTML you are using?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to change the **position attribute to fixed**, for the vertical bar.

```
.generalMenuHome
{
    position:fixed;
}
```